# How to deselect the values from state after selecting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, thirdweb

I am building an app in this after selecting the specific NFT a new div with extra content will show up. The selecting part is working fine but now I want it to be able to deselect it.
This is the state

```
const [selectedNFT, setSelectedNFT] = useState<NFT>();
```

and this is the function for selecting the NFT

```
{ownedNfts?.data?.map((nft) => (
        <div
          onClick={() => setSelectedNFT(nft)}
          className={`flex flex-col space-y-2 card min-w-fit border-2 bg-gray-100 
          ${
            nft.metadata.id === selectedNFT?.metadata?.id
              ? "border-black scale-105 z-50"
              : "border-transparent"
          }`}
          key={nft.metadata.id}
        >
```

the onClick events populate the state but what I want is that after clicking on it again it should remove the data from the state making the state empty again

Comment: What do you want to do? remove deselceted value from state, update the dom with new values, can you more specific and share more code?

Comment: the selectedNFT state is populated with the nft I selected but now I want to deselect it by clicking on It again.

what code do you require I mean the code related to this, is this part that I shared

Comment: You need to post more of your code.

Comment: Okay, I have updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check if the `nft` is the current state, if so set it empty or whatever the desired value else set it to state .. (assuming you are putting only one `nft` in to `selectedNFT`)

```
onClick={() => {
   selectedNFT === nft ? setSelectedNFT("") : setSelectedNFT(nft)
}
```

Comment: yes, may be just `setselectedNFT(undefined)` ?

Comment: Yes i did it thank you buddy